# Java resources after export project

Tags: java, resources, jar, derby

I've done a java aplication that have some images as resources like this:

> ->src
>       ->resources
>         ->images

For accessing this resources i've used getClass().getResource("/resources/images/img.jpg"), this works fine when i am on eclipse, but when i export the project to a jar the path change to something this genre: "jar:C:/path/deployed.jar!/resources/images/img.jpg".

What i am doing wrong? It is possible to export all the project in one jar?

One more question, this resources include a derby db that dont work either when deployed in jar file

Thanks

Comment: I can't imagine how Derby would work inside of a jar file since resources in a Jar file are read only.

Comment: The db is only for read data, there are no insert's.

Answer (score 2):

Try using getResourceAsStream() instead of getResource() to access resources in your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

> One more question, this resources include a derby db that dont work either when deployed in jar file

As Hovercraft stated, Derby DB (meaning the data files, not implementation) won't start from a jar. And it doesn't matter you don't insert anything, Derby needs to open these files for writing. They need to be in a directory where you have writing access.